# Phenomenological threshold estimates for rotated surface code

Tags: error-correction, surface-code

I am trying to find threshold estimates for the rotated surface code for depolarizing phenomenological/circuit-level noise with and without measurement errors (I am aware that those might be implementation dependent).

For error rate $p$ and measurement error rate $q$, I was able to find the following data:

**Toric code** [[1](https://arxiv.org/abs/1302.3428)]:

- For $q=0$ (phenomenological): 18.9%
- For $p=q$ (phenomenological): 2.9%
- For $p=q$ (circuit-level): 1.1 - 1.4%

**(Rotated) surface code**:

- For $p=q$ (phenomenological, X-Z errors): 3.2% [[2](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1612.04795.pdf)]
- For $p=q$ (circuit-level): 0.4 - 1.1% [[3](https://arxiv.org/abs/1208.0928), [4](https://arxiv.org/abs/1404.3747)]

**Question:** Are there papers that explicitly evaluate the rotated surface code and provide numbers? I expected that the values would be easier to find, given the recent experiments by the Google Quantum team [[5](https://arxiv.org/abs/2207.06431)]. Would it be correct to assume that the values are not too far off from the actual thresholds?

[1](https://arxiv.org/abs/1302.3428) Terhal (2015), [Quantum Error Correction for Quantum Memories](https://arxiv.org/abs/1302.3428)
[2](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1612.04795.pdf) Yoder and Kim (2017), [The surface code with a twist](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1612.04795.pdf)
[3](https://arxiv.org/abs/1208.0928) Fowler et al. (2012), [Surface codes: Towards practical large-scale quantum computation](https://arxiv.org/abs/1208.0928)
[4](https://arxiv.org/abs/1404.3747) Tomita and Svore (2014), [Low-distance Surface Codes under Realistic Quantum Noise](https://arxiv.org/abs/1404.3747)
[5](https://arxiv.org/abs/2207.06431) Google (2022), [Suppressing quantum errors by scaling a surface code logical qubit](https://arxiv.org/abs/2207.06431)

Comment: Formally, the thresholds for the rotated and unrotated surface codes should be identical, since the threshold is a property of the thermodynamic (infinite-size) limit and does not depend on the boundaries of the problem. There might be small differences from paper to paper depending on the details of the noise model, decoder, and finite sizes used to estimate the transition.

Comment: Thank you @JahanClaes as a non-physicist I didn't think about it this way. So for the rotated surface code the phenomenological noise with $p=q$ will be at least worse than 2.9%. Do you happen to know of any more recent numerical results?

Comment: Experiments don't care about phenom noise because they don't have access to magical 4-body measurements. They have to decompose into available gates; they care about circuit noise. If anything, phenom will get harder to find over time because it's not a good approximation of reality.